# Connecting a lua state to another one

Tags: lua

I am using Lua to extend my C++ application. My application have some parts(ex: `timer event`, `ui events`) that can be extended by Lua, so for each part, I make a new state and load files and functions related to that part in it, so making a change to a part and reloading it wont affect the other parts.

Now I am in a situation that I need some **general** files to be shared among all other parts.

like for example : I am making a function for the timer events part, and there is a object defined in those general files i want to change its info in this function.
Now i am in the ui event part and I  need when i access that object in the general file I want it to contain the changes that was made from the ui part.

So I thought about creating another state for those and like make an __index for the global table in the other state to search this state if they don't find some stuff in it:)) *apparently I don't know how to make that*.

I hope someone get what I mean and tell me how to make that?!

Comment: You might want to use coroutines or use one of the existing Lua multithreading modules, [I like this comparison](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/comparison.html). Most of them should be able to handle what you want in some way or another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua states created with `lua_newstate` or `lua_newstate` are completely separated and cannot directly talk to each other: you need to copy data manually from one state to the other.

You can set an __index metamethod for the global table in one state to look for the data in the other one, but you'll have to do it in C or export a function to Lua that does that.

Comment: Thanks, for info I was skeptic that I can to something like that. I would go for exprting lua function :)